# Reasonable key types for map used to set properties of related classes?

Tags: c++

I'm planning to write a code with classes that have inheritance relationships like the following and have various properties that are associated with material types:

1. Abstract base class `Foo`. No properties associated with it.
2. `Foo1GeneralElastic` inherits from class Foo and has the properties associated with a *possibly* anisotropic elastic material.
3. `Foo2GeneralElastic` also inherits from class Foo and has the same kinds of material properties as `Foo1GeneralElastic`, but is otherwise different.
4. `Foo1PiezoElastic` inherits from `Foo1GeneralElastic` and has both piezoelectric properties as well as generic elastic ones.
5. `Foo1IsotropicElastic` inherits from `Foo1GeneralElastic`, but does not share its properties.

I decided that the abstract base class would have one or more methods that take a map of type `MyPropMap`, defined as:

```
typedef std::map<PropertyLabel,std::vector<double> > MyPropMap
```

I have a few different options on what the PropertyLabel type could be, and I'm trying to weigh the pros and cons of each:

**Have the PropertyLabel be an `enum`**: This would be lightweight, but it would basically be a bag of labels for all the different properties of every material that I'm considering.

**Have the PropertyLabel be just an `int`**: Here, I'd have separate header files for each material type, each of which would contain definition of static integer constants that would be labels for the relevant material properties. For example, `MatPropKeyGenElastic.hpp` would define the integer constant `ELASTICITY_MATRIX`, `MatPropKeyIsotropicElastic.hpp` would define the constants `ELASTIC_MODULUS` and `POISSONS_RATIO`, and `MatPropKeyPiezoElastic.hpp` would `#include` the file `MatPropKeyGenElastic.hpp` and additionally define the constant `PIEZO_CONST_MATRIX`.

The tricky thing would be to make sure that none of the constants that could be used together would have the same values. That could be accomplished by generating the header files with a script that would set the values of these constants to unique values.

**Have the PropertyLabel be a `std::string`** From here I could take things a few different ways. I could just have string literals like `"ELASTICITY_MATRIX"` in the code and rely on these literals never being misspelled---an error that would be caught at run-time rather than compile time. I could define string constants in way analogous to the scheme above for integer constants, and the task of keeping the constants unique would be trivial: just set the value of `ELASTICITY_MATRIX` to `"ELASTICITY_MATRIX"`, the value of `POISSONS_RATIO` to `"POISSONS_RATIO"`, etc.

The catch I see with that, aside from the extra overhead, is that I've seen horror stories relating to global static constants of non-PODs, such as those in the comments in the topics [non-integral constants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151831/non-integral-constants/) and [Defining class string constants in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/459942/defining-class-string-constants-in-c/). I suppose that I could have the global static constants be `const char[]` arrays, which are PODs that would be implicitly converted into `std::string`s when used as map keys (and, *no*, I am not planning on letting the map key itself be `const char*`). I could also define the string literals with the preprocessor, but then I couldn't keep them within a namespace.

Would you recommend any of the above approaches? Are there hidden traps in them that I hadn't noticed? Are there still other approaches that you would recommend?

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend to use strings. It's too expensive for such simple task. I vote for enum.

But if it looks too ugly to you to keep all label constants in a single place, you could elaborate more complex approach - use a composite key like pair of two numbers - (class ID, property ID).

Both could be defined as enums, maybe nested. Moreover, class ID could be generated automatically - e.g. using `reinterpret_cast` on `std::type_info` pointer or just using `std::type_info` pointer or `std::type_index` if supported. Illustrating idea with code:

```
// PropertyLabel type, could be used as associative container key
struct PropertyLabel: std::pair<const std::type_info*, int>
{
  // Template ctor allows implicit conversion from enums
  // (actually not only from enums but from any int-compatible types)
  // Uncomment explicit keyword if implicit conversions scares you and use
  // explicit conversion syntax - PropertyLabel(smth).
  template <typename T> /*explicit*/ PropertyLabel(T label):
     std::pair<const std::type_info*, int>(&typeid(T), label)
  {
  }
};

// First property holder 
class PropertyUser1
{
public:
  enum Labels
  {
     eProperty1,
     eProperty2,
     eProperty3,
  };
 };

// Second property holder 
class PropertyUser2
{
public:
  enum Labels
  {
     eProperty1,// Due to class scope you could use same names for different properties
     eProperty2,
     eProperty3,
  };
 };

// Usage. A bit dangerous due to implicit conversions, but intuitive and handy:
MyPropMap properties;
properties[PropertyUser1::eProperty1].push_back(42.0);
properties[PropertyUser2::eProperty1].push_back(42.42);
// Will be with explicit ctor:
// properties[PropertyLabel(PropertyUser1::eProperty1)].push_back(42.0);
// properties[PropertyLabel(PropertyUser2::eProperty1)].push_back(42.42);
```

Looks like it could be improved with more type safety eliminating possibility of using non-enum types like `int`, e.g. disabling calls like `PropertyLabel(42)`. But this is just to illustrate idea.

Comment: Is it me, or is that PropertyLabel struct inheriting from std::pair?

Comment: I took a closer look at the code, and compiled a test program with it. It works for me but depends on the addresses of typeid(PropertyUser1::Labels) and typeid(PropertyUser2::Labels) being different, since in each class, eProperty1 has the same integer value. I would be leery about trusting this to always be the case. Since PropertyUser1::Labels and PropertyUser2::Labels are basically both ints, I can see another compiler having the addresses of their typeids being &typeid(int), and the code would then fail horribly.

Comment: @jjramsey `PropertyUserX::Labels` is not `int`, it's user defined enum creating different type and it shall refer to different `type_info` instances. But if you don't trust your compiler you could create your own wrapper for `type_info` pointer and use `operator==()` (and e.g. 'before()' for `std::less`) which is guarantied to return false for different types, even enums. Or just use `std::type_index` if supported on your compiler.

Comment: @jjramsey Correct,  PropertyLabel struct inherits from std::pair. Just to not mess with own 'operator<()' implemenetation.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized a relatively simple solution that would give me pretty much what I want without too much fuss. For any particular instance of the `MyPropMap` type, I'm dealing with the properties of *one* particular kind of material: isotropic elastic, piezoelectric, anisotropic elastic, and so on. Given this, I can wrap the enums corresponding to each material type in its own namespace and put them in the appropriate header file, so for example,

```
// MatPropKey/IsotropicElastic.hpp:
namespace IsotropicElastic {
   enum { ELASTIC_MODULUS, POISSONS_RATIO };
}

// MatPropKey/GenElastic.hpp
namespace GenElastic {
   enum { ELASTICITY_MATRIX }
}

// MatPropKey/PiezoElastic.hpp
namespace PiezoElastic {
   enum { PIEZO_CONST_MATRIX, ELASTICITY_MATRIX }
}
```

There is some redundancy here, but I can live with that. So long as I stick to the above convention, then within each namespace, the `enum` values are unique, and so long as I only use the `enum` values within a particular namespace for each instance of `MyPropMap`---which I want to do anyway---I'm fine. (Realistically, I'd also want to wrap each of these namespaces within a common `MPKey` namespace.) Of course, this isn't foolproof. A sufficiently creative fool could, for example, decide to `#include` both `GenElastic.hpp` and `PiezoElastic.hpp` and then use `GenElastic::ELASTICITY_MATRIX` with the `PiezoElastic::PIEZO_CONST_MATRIX`. Bad things could then happen. Still, the code communicates how the named constants are supposed to be grouped, and avoiding unwanted name clashes is trivial.

Wish I thought of it earlier.

Answer (score 0):

After some thought, I realized a few things:

1. It's better to wrap the map within a class, so that I have a bit more control over how it is written.
2. Even the wrapped map is generic and has to be able to accommodate any material parameter type, so there's only so much compile-type safety that I can provide.

Given this, I decided to design a `MatProp` class roughly as follows:

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>

class MatProp {
public:
   // Skipping the constructor details ...

   void setProp_Raw(int propId, double val);
   void getProp_Raw(int propId, double & val) const;

   void setProp_Raw(int propId, const std::vector<double> & vals);
   void getProp_Raw(int propId, std::vector<double> & vals) const;

   // More overloaded set/get funcs for complex scalars and vectors ...

private:
   // The typedef allows me to write MatPropMap_::iterator, etc. in the
   // implementation of the member functions, which is handy if, say, 
   // I want to swap the std::map for an unordered_map later on.
   typedef std::map<PropertyLabel,std::vector<double> > MatPropMap_;

   MatPropMap_ matPropMap_;

};
```

The set/get functions are suffixed with `_Raw` because it's easy to put in a wrong combination of property ID and value. I could pass in information to the constructor of `MatProp` so that the inputs to these functions could be validated at run time, but setting that up could get clunky and make the class harder to use. To add some extra safety, I can do this, for example:

```
void setIsotropicLinearElasticParameter(MatProps mProp,
          ElasPropEnum propId, // ELASTIC_MODULUS and POISSONS_RATIO are the 
                               // *only* valid values of this parameter.
          double val) {
    mProp.setParam_Raw(propId, val);
}
```

The function is simple, but I'm declaring clearly that (1) only two keys are allowed and (2) they really are supposed to be of type `double`. The interface isn't totally foolproof, but it's fairly easy to use correctly and takes some effort to use wrong. FWIW, a similar thing was done here: http://blog.knatten.org/2010/04/23/make-apis-hard-to-use-incorrectly/.

Comment: Come to think of it, I probably do need some run-time safety, but since this is a forum for answering questions, not for my speculations on how I might do stuff (which will probably be revised anyway), I'll leave my (two!) answers to my own questions as they are.